# variable not found in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, socket.io

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
from time import localtime, strftime

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get('user')
        session["username"] = username

    else:
        return render_template("login.html") 


@app.route("/chatroom",methods=["GET", "POST"])
def chatroom():
    user = session.get("username")
    return render_template("Chat.html",users=user)    


@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):
    print(f"{data}")    
    send(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

HTML Code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
<title>Creating new channel</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'css/chat.css')}}" />
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'js/chat.js')}}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'images/Logo.png')}}"><br><br>
<div class="formdiv">
    <!-- <div class="create-channel-div">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Create Channel" autocomplete="off" /><br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Create Channel</button>
    </div> -->
    <div class="stored-channels-div"></div>

    <div class="message-typed-div">
        <input type="text" name="inputMessage" class="message-entered" placeholder="Type your message" />
        <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <!-- <p class="username-entered">{{users}}</p> -->
    <div class="displaying-message-div">

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const userdata = `{{users}}`;
    alert(userdata)
</script>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var socket = io.connect(
    location.protocol + "//" + document.domain + ":" + location.port
  );
  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    const br = document.createElement('br');
    const span_user = document.createElement('span');
    span_user.innerHTML = data.userdata;
    p.innerHTML = span_user.outerHTML + br.outerHTML + data.msg + br.outerHTML;
    document.querySelector('.displaying-message-div').append(p);
  });
  document.querySelector('.submit-btn').onclick = () => {
    socket.send({'msg':document.querySelector('.message-entered').value, 'userdata':userdata});
  };
});
```

I am creating a chat application in which i am trying to print the name of the user along with the message which he/she has typed (similar to skype or whatsapp). But when i run this program the **alert message under the const userdata gives a none**. So the question i have is that am i getting the username from session in a wrong way or what is the problem.

Comment: Python's `None` means the variable has no value, so what that means is a) transferring the value from flask to JS works fine b) `session.get("username")` is empty

Comment: i am not able to figure out why is it returning no value into the users

Comment: Your /login POST route doesn't render anything; I'd make sure the login actually works.